# HorizontalScroll when update TextView

Tags: android, scroll, textview

I am writing a calculator, it has one textview and many buttons. If I press on some button, textview will add a new character at the end of string. And automatically scroll to this char in right direction. And it works, but the older characters (at left) are cutting and if I scroll to right i will see a empty space.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="50sp" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Look at this. I input 123456789123456789. Numbers from 1 to 7 are not visible. And white space at right position is exactly for 7 numbers.

[image: It is the left available position when scrollbar]

[image: It is the right available position when scrollbar]

I read a lot of answers, but all it don't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly why does that happen but I can recommend you a way to avoid it. Remove the `layout_gravity` from the `TextView` and add `android:scrollbars="none"` to the `HorizontalScrollView`:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true" 
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"            
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="50sp" />
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Then in code, when you modify the text on the `TextView` add the code below to "move" the `HorizontalScrollView` to the right position:

```
mHorizontalScroll.post(new Runnable() {

        @Override
    public void run() {             
        mHorizontalScroll.scrollTo(mScroll.getWidth(), 0);
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I change my textView in many parts of code. Does it exist a way to look while textView will be change?(Maybe any onchangelistener) I want to make my code clean.

Comment: @pavelartlover No there isn't. But you could always create a method in your activity that will set the text and also post that `Runnable` so when the user enters some digits you just need to call that method.